# How do I fix fatal error U1033: syntax error: "$(MAKE)" in CLion?

Tags: c, clion

so I was trying to run my first Code in CLion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int x;
    x = 5/2;

    printf("Result: %.2f", x);
    return 0;
}
```

and received following error message:

```
makefile(136) : fatal error U1033: syntax error: "$(MAKE)" unexpected stop.
```

I'm looking forward for a reply.

Comment: As a side note: your code will invoke *undefined behavior* for type mismatch: `%.2f` expects `double` but `int` is passed.

Comment: Appreciate your helpful side note MikeCAT. Thank you.